An SQL tool for Linux where the ad-hoc data editing is as seamless as pgAdmin III
In pgAdmin III, when viewing a table, you could add rows and populate their cells with the same minimal effort as in spreadsheet software (tab to move to the next cell, enter to move to the next row).  This made pgAdmin III handy to use for my small SQL-based budget forecaster.
pgAdmin 4 unfortunately regressed in this area.  At least with the version officially supported by my distro, editing a single cell requires tab-tab-space to finish editing and another tab to go to the next cell, then alt+shift+A to add a new row.
I'd keep using pgAdmin III just for this, but on newer versions of PostgreSQL, it errors out trying to even view the list of tables in the nav tree.
There are lots of alternatives out there, but none seem to mention this specific functionality among their features.
I prefer a real Linux desktop app, but if there's a web-based solution, that's fine too.

Try SQuirreL - it's quite good - been ages since I used it - strictly a CLI man these days!

I really like Beekeeper Studio Community, it is TAB and ENTER it does the things you expect.
Another alternative I will mention is DBeaver Community.
Be careful both products have a free Community version and a pro version which is paid.

Thanks, Beekeeper looked promising, but it seems flaky in practice.  You can't just type and tab, especially on text fields, where it just discards your input when you tab.  The only way to get a text PK to stick seems to be to type, then find the "apply" button in the lower-right corner of the screen and click it.  Is DBeaver better when it comes to more fluid data input?

I haven't used it for a long time, so unfortunately I can't give you any advice. Sorry, I must have misunderstood you. I'll leave the answer, maybe it will be useful to someone.

Finally got around to trying DBeaver CE.  A bit better than Beekeeper in this regard, but the "enter to go to a new row" equivalent workflow is still cumbersome: First you must Ctrl+S to save the current row, then Alt+Insert to create a new one.  Thanks anyway for the suggestions.
